# Error when running take() after create RDD with sc.textFile()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm working with PySpark in Jupyter Notebook, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to execute the take() operation after create RDD with the `sc.textFile` method. The code I'm using is as follows:

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")\
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "2g")\
    .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

patents = sc.textFile("./data/apat63_99.txt")
patents.take(10)
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I execute take(), I get an error. However, if I wait for a considerable amount of time (around 10-15 seconds) and then re-run take(), it executes successfully and returns the expected results.

I would like to understand the cause of this behavior and how to resolve it. Why do I need to wait for some time after creating the Spark context in order to execute take() without errors? Are there any additional configurations or considerations that I should be aware of when working with PySpark in Jupyter Notebook?

It's important to mention that this error only happens with take() or with first(), but if I use collect() this error doesn't happen

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Details:

- `./data/apat63_99.txt` size: 225 MB
- `pyspark --version`: 3.4.0
- `python --version`: 3.11.1

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 4
      1 import time
      2 patents = sc.textFile("./data/apat63_99.txt")
----> 4 patents.take(10)

File C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py:2836, in RDD.take(self, num)
   2833         taken += 1
   2835 p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 2836 res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   2838 items += res
   2839 partsScanned += numPartsToTry

File C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py:2319, in SparkContext.runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   2317 mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
   2318 assert self._jvm is not None
-> 2319 sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   2320 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))

File C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File C:\spark\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    167 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    168     try:
--> 169         return f(*a, **kw)
    170     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    171         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (host.docker.internal executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1035)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:127)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:112)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:490)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:320)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:734)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2088)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:274)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1035)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:127)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:112)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:490)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:320)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:734)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2088)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:274)
```